# Funções de Saudações "Bom dia, Boa tarde e Boa noite"

Tags: javascript, algoritmo, revisão-de-código

Hoje deparei-me em um tópico bem interessante, que são as saudações "*Bom dia*, *Boa tarde* e *Boa noite*" em **JavaScript** (e entre outras linguagens..)

Onde na tentativa falha de criar um código simples, pequeno e fácil também *"dei de cara"* com algumas eventualidades. Segue o código abaixo:

```js
var h = new Date('May 31, 2021 09:00:00').getHours(); // alterna entre 06, 12, 18, 00
var greetings = ['Boa madrugada', 'Bom dia', 'Boa tarde', 'Boa noite'];

console.log(greetings[h / 6]); // dividindo a hora por 6, seu resultado servirá para encontrar a posição do valor na Array
```

Tinha tudo para dar certo, porém os valores das horas atuais, entre o **6** e **12** (*7, 8, 9, ...*), o **12** e **18** (*13, 14, 15, ...*) e o **18** e **00** (*19, 20, 21, ...*).

Os valores entre eles consequentemente não são encontrados no `Array` pelo resultado da divisão por 6 da hora atual, a não ser que a `Array` tivesse seus respectivos valores de acordo com o resultado.

entre:

- 06 e 12 = Bom dia
- 12 e 18 = Boa tarde
- 18 e 00 = Boa noite
- 00 e 05 = Boa madrugada

---

#### Dando uma aplicada ..

Cheguei neste resultado que de certa forma "sanou" o problema!

```js
const greetingMessage = () => {
  let h = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('pt-BR', {hour: 'numeric', hour12: false}); // formato 24 horas (0-23)
  if (h >= 0 && h <= 5) { // entre meia noite (0h) e 5 da madrugada
    return 'Boa madrugada';
  } else if (h >= 6 && h < 12) { // entre 6 e 11 da manhã
    return 'Bom dia';
  } else if (h >= 12 && h < 18) { // entre meio dia (12h) e 17 (5h) da tarde
    return 'Boa tarde';
  } else if (h >= 18 && h <= 23) { // entre 18 (6h) e 23 (11h) da noite
    return 'Boa noite';
  }
}

console.log(greetingMessage());
```

mas teria alguma forma mais "limpa" sem requer o uso de tantos **IFs**/**Else**?

<sup>**Obs**: a intenção é deixar o código com menos linhas possível!</sup>

Comment: Pra pegar o valor numérico das horas, basta fazer `new Date().getHours()`, que retorna o valor entre 0 e 23. `toLocaleTimeString` retorna uma string, que depois é convertida automaticamente para número (por causa das regras dos operadores de comparação), mas se a ideia é comparar números, então obter o valor como número desde o começo é mais simples e recomendado

Comment: @hkotsubo sim sim, obrigado pela observação, como foi algo nas pressas, realmente passou despercebido! é até dinâmico refatorar essa variável, a linha reduz bastante em termos de quantidade de caracteres. Não irei alterar na pergunta, optei por deixar essa correção na edição da resposta do Augusto Vasques

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Edit:

Como informado no comentário do [hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/511294/fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-de-sauda%C3%A7%C3%B5es-bom-dia-boa-tarde-e-boa-noite/511296?noredirect=1#comment950695_511296) facilita a adoção do método [`Date.prototype.getHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours) que retorna a hora para a data especificada, de acordo com a hora local.
Então as linhas:

```javascript
let h = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('pt-BR', { 
   hour: 'numeric',
   hour12: false 
});
```

Foram substituídas por:

```javascript
let h = new Date().getHours();
```

### Algumas possíveis refatorações para seu código:

- #### Usando declaração condicional [`if`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else).

```js
const greetingMessage = () => {
  //let h = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('pt-BR', { hour: 'numeric', hour12: false });
  let h = new Date().getHours();
  if (h <= 5) return 'Boa madrugada';
  if (h < 12) return 'Bom dia';
  if (h < 18) return 'Boa tarde';
  return 'Boa noite';
}

console.log(greetingMessage());
```

- ### Usando a declaração condicional [`switch/case`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).

```js
const greetingMessage = () => {
  //let h = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('pt-BR', { hour: 'numeric', hour12: false }); 
  let h = new Date().getHours();
  switch (true) {
    case h <= 5: return 'Boa madrugada';
    case h < 12: return 'Bom dia';
    case h < 18: return 'Boa tarde';
    default: return 'Boa noite';
  }      
}

console.log(greetingMessage());
```

- ### Usando o operador [condicional ternário](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

```js
const greetingMessage = () => {
  //let h = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('pt-BR', { hour: 'numeric', hour12: false });
  let h = new Date().getHours();
  return (h <= 5) ? 'Boa madrugada' :
         (h < 12) ? 'Bom dia' :
         (h < 18) ? 'Boa tarde' :
         'Boa noite';
}

console.log(greetingMessage());
```

- ### Usando matemática.

```js
const greetingMessage = () => {
  var greetings = ['Boa madrugada', 'Bom dia', 'Boa tarde', 'Boa noite'];
  //let h = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('pt-BR', { hour: 'numeric', hour12: false });
  let h = new Date().getHours();
  return greetings[(h / 6) >> 0];   //Trunca o resultado da divisão obtendo sempre um inteiro.
}

console.log(greetingMessage());
```

Comment: Maravilha Augusto!! deu uma turbinada legal.. só não entendi o uso do operador **>>** seria ele *"maior maior que zero"*?

Comment: @gleisin-dev Veja  na documentação [Deslocamento para a direita >>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Right_shift). No caso é um hack para truncar um número fazendo o deslocar 0(zero) bits para direita, assim retornando somente a parte inteira desse número.

Comment: Poderia ser também `return greetings[~~(h / 6)];` ou então `return greetings[Math.trunc(h / 6)];`

Comment: interessante, vou dar uma olhada!!

Comment: Não é mais simples usar `new Date().getHours()`?

Comment: @hkotsubo, eu estava concentrado lá no META, agora posso o dar melhor atenção. Você diz aqui `let h = new Date().getHours();` sim com certeza é um bom aprimoramento do código.

Comment: Sim, é isso mesmo :-)

Comment: @hkotsubo Eu já estou fazendo a edição de todos trechos de código. Desculpe por  não o dar atenção no primeiro momento.

Comment: Sem problemas

Answer (score -2):

var agora = new Date()
var horas = agora.getHours()
console.log(`Agora sao exatamente ${horas} horas.`)
if (horas >=0 && horas <6 ) {
console.log('boa madrugada')
} else if (horas <= 12 ) {
console.log('boa dia!')
} else if (horas <= 18){
console.log('boa tarde!')
} else if (horas <= 23){
console.log('boa noite')
}